# FileSystemObject not recognized even with reference to scrrun.dll

Tags: excel, vba

This should be easy but I cannot get it to even compile.  I've used "regsvr32 scrrun.dll" and rebooted to no avail.  Here's the code:

```
Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim destpath As String
Dim sourcepath As String
Dim filename As String

sourcepath = "\\spap097\VISIONFILES\Attachments"    
destpath = "\\spap097\VISIONFILES\Attachments\Temp Folder for 35870 Visions Files"
filename = "test.docx"

' now do the copy
fso.CopyFile(sourcepath & "\" & filename, destpath & "\" & filename)
```

Any assistance is very appreciated.

Comment: I get a compile error on the "CopyFile" statement.  It is as if I did not add the Tools, Reference, Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

Comment: What is the specific error message?

Comment: I have amended your code and it now works. + I gave a better alternative as well.

Comment: Thanks for all your assistance.  Turns out we have a group policy here at work that does not allow file copying.  Now I need to go get permission.

Comment: What has group policy to do with the error message :) You will get a permission denied error if you don't have Rights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a better alternative.

Your 9 lines of code can be reduced to 7 lines

```
Dim destpath As String
Dim sourcepath As String
Dim filename As String

sourcepath = "\\spap097\VISIONFILES\Attachments"
destpath = "\\spap097\VISIONFILES\Attachments\Temp Folder for 35870 Visions Files"
filename = "test.docx"

FileCopy sourcepath & "\" & filename, destpath & "\" & filename
```

or further to 5 lines

```
Dim destpath As String, sourcepath As String, filename As String

sourcepath = "\\spap097\VISIONFILES\Attachments"
destpath = "\\spap097\VISIONFILES\Attachments\Temp Folder for 35870 Visions Files"
filename = "test.docx"

FileCopy sourcepath & "\" & filename, destpath & "\" & filename
```

You may also want to see the MSDN article on `FILECOPY` [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264390.aspx)

Quote from the link in case it dies.

[image]

**EDIT**

**Solution to your problem**

Set reference to `Tools | Reference | Microsoft Scripting Runtime` in case you are early binding. `Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject` And in case you are late binding i.e `Dim fso As Object` then you don't need to set the reference.

There was an error in the line `fso.CopyFile(sourcepath & "\" & filename, destpath & "\" & filename)` You had brackets `()`

```
Sub Sample()
    '~~> Any of the below will work.
    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject        
    'Dim fso As Object

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Dim destpath As String
    Dim sourcepath As String
    Dim filename As String

    sourcepath = "\\spap097\VISIONFILES\Attachments"
    destpath = "\\spap097\VISIONFILES\Attachments\Temp Folder for 35870 Visions Files"
    filename = "test.docx"

    ' now do the copy
    fso.CopyFile sourcepath & "\" & filename, destpath & "\" & filename
End Sub
```